# Firebase Analytics - Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, data-retrieval

I´m trying to implement Firebase Analytcs into my app.
But I can´t see any data at Debugview or Dashboard.

In log I can see a message "W/FA: Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance ID"

I don't know if this is the problem.

This is my code:

```
public static void logEvents(String event, String category, String action, Context context){

   FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setAppicationId("MY_APPLICATION_ID")
   .setApiKey("MY_API_KEY")
   .build();
   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context,options);

   mFireBase = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("ga_category",catetory);
   bundle.putString("ga_action",action);
   bundle.putString("ga_label",label);

   mFireBase.logEvent("eventoga",bundle);

}
```

Someone could help?

Best,

Comment: Does your logcat contain any other FA warnings or errors.  For example: `E/FA: GoogleService failed to initialize` or `E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled`?

Comment: No, it didn't any E/FA or W/FA. I changed the code (updated above). I stopped to receive the "Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance ID" but I still seeing nothing at Firebase Dashboard or DebugView.

Comment: Normally, Firebase initialization is performed by `FirebaseInitProvider` and a call to `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` is not needed.  See the [description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp).  You should explore what the default initialization by `FirebaseInitProvider` is not occurring.  You don't want to be re-initializing Firebase everytime `logEvents()` is called.

Comment: @FlávioLeal Is GooglePlayServices up to date on the device you're testing with?

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit late, but I just had that issue today and figured this myself:

In my particular case the corresponding setting for `gcm_defaultSenderId` was missing, adding this, resolved the issue. So in total my app needed the following 3 options set to run: `gcm_defaultSenderId, google_api_key, google_app_id`. I leave it to you to figure the corresponding setter, as I have these values in `values\strings.xml`.

Note: The usual answer here is, to use the google services plugin in gradle, but I am aware of reasons not to do this.